# CodeIgniter(2.1.4) Sessions is not working

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have a problem with CI sessions.
I initialized my session library:

`$autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’, ‘session’) (In config/autoload.php)`

This is my code:

```
cycle

$this->load->library(‘image_moo’);
// Upload image and return unique name
  $data = array(
  ‘image’ => $image,
  );

$this->db->insert(‘category_images’, $data);


  if (!$this->session->userdata(‘uploadImages’))
  {
  $this->session->set_userdata(‘uploadImages’, $this->db->insert_id());
  }
  else
  {
  $session = $this->session->userdata(‘uploadImages’);
  $sessionData = $session.’|’.$this->db->insert_id();
  $this->session->set_userdata(“uploadImages”, $sessionData);
  } 

  echo $this->session->userdata(‘uploadImages’); // return 256; corect result - 255|256

  end of cycle
```

This is script for image upload with jQuery File Upload (blueimp) and i need set ids of inserted in database images to session.

Can anyone help. Thank you!

Comment: The code looks fine, I doubt it's the session problem. I'm thinking the app flow might be a problem. Where do you initially set the session value - this looks as it only works when you upload one image, then go and upload another.

Comment: This example is for two images uploaded. Script is for multiple upload. Images is uploaded on ftp and inseted in database. Only problem is returned ids - session.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get all the images as a batch then, instead of one by one?

Comment: Yes. Images pass one by one.

Answer (score 1):

To use `CI Session` you also need to provide the encryption key in your `application/config.php`:

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'xxxxxx';`
```

Comment: I know, it's set. Also have a loggin system and he works. Code:  if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('login');
        } //works

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cycle

    $this->load->library(‘image_moo’);
    // Upload image and return unique name
      $data = array(
      ‘image’ => $image,
      );

    $this->db->insert(‘category_images’, $data);


      if ($this->session->userdata(‘uploadImages’)=='')// or if (!isset($this->session->userdata(‘uploadImages’)))
      {
      $this->session->set_userdata(‘uploadImages’, $this->db->insert_id());
      }
      else
      {
      $session = $this->session->userdata(‘uploadImages’);
      $sessionData = $session.’|’.$this->db->insert_id();
      $this->session->set_userdata(“uploadImages”, $sessionData);
      } 

      echo $this->session->userdata(‘uploadImages’); // return 256; corect result - 255|256

end of cycle
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already try this one. Still doesn't work. Btw with "isset" return fatal error. :)